# Как правильно пользоваться свойством IsVisible С# xamarin , wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

Вопрос весьма глупый, возможно поэтому не могу найти на него четкий ответ. В разработке своего приложения я пользуюсь паттерном `MVVM`, стараюсь придерживаться его "Правил" если так можно сказать. На моей `View` расположен список с сообщениями, соответственно , когда мне надо открыть эту страницу каждый раз для нужного диалога я подгружаю нужные сообщения и добавляю их в список. На `ViewModel` я просто обрабатываю данные из модели, в самой `Model` находится приватный список и публичные методы для работы с ним. Так вот, сообщения могут быть разными , аудио, обычные , с прикрепленными файлами. Каждый раз когда я выгружаю сообщение на экран , я определяю тип сообщения и отталкиваясь от этого начинаю выставлять кучу свойств `visible`: Например если сообщение обыкновенное то кнопку и ползунок для перемотки видео приходится ставить в `IsVisible=false`. Выставив все свойства я добавляю объект в список , который отобразится на экране
Вот небольшой отрывок кода в котором я обрабатываю данные

```
  foreach (var item in Temp.Reverse())
         {
          // Уточняем явялется ли сообщение шифрованным
          var flag_Line_Correct = GetLineCorrect(item.Message);
          if (flag_Line_Correct)
             item.Message = EncryptionService.GetDecript(item.Message);
    
          SetStartParametr_Message(item);
          if (item.Files.Count != 0)
             item.IsVisibleFile = true;
         item.Files = await FileDb.GetFile(item.message_id);
         item.Receiver_id = (int)contentJobjects["receiver_id"];
         GroupMessage.Add(new Grouping<ChatModel, FileModel>(item, item.Files)); 
                        await ChatDbService.AddMessage(item);
                        // MessageList.Add(item);
         }
  private ChatModel SetStartParametr_Message(ChatModel item)
        {
            if (item.Audio != null)
            {
                
                item.IsMessageVisible = false;
                item.ValueSlider = 0.0;
                item.MaximumSlider = 1;
                item.TypeMessage = "audio";
                item.IsAuidoVisible = true;
                item.SourceImage = "play.png";
                item.Chat_room_id = Room_id;
                item.Receiver_id = Rec_id;

            }
            else
            {
                item.TypeMessage = "message";
                item.ValueSlider = 0.0;
                item.MaximumSlider = 1;
                item.IsMessageVisible = true;
                item.IsAuidoVisible = false;
                item.Chat_room_id = Room_id;
                item.Receiver_id = Rec_id;
            }
            return item;
        } // SetStartParametr_Message
```

Кроме того, на форме есть диалоговое окно, которое изначально просто имеет свойство `IsVisible = false` , нажимая на кнопку прикрепить файл , оно становиться `IsVisible=true`. И это только часть тех вещей которым я меню это свойство. Подскажите , нормальная ли эта практика так делать. Или их по надобности лучше отрисовывать через код, на сколько это возможно?

Comment: Так Xamarin или WPF? В WPF есть Style/DataTrigger в XAML, например если свойство null, то не отображать. В каком формате оно в Xamaring реализовано, не знаю. Но вьюмодель не должна отвечать за поведение вьюхи. Вьюмодель должна предоставлять данные и события их обновления. Другими словами вот это `item.Audio != null` должно быть в тригерах в XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если наличие каких-либо даных исключет наличие других данных, то заведите несколько типов и используйте наследование.

```
public abstract class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AudioMessage : Message
{
    public Uri Audio { get; set; }
}

public class TextMessage : Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Uri[] Images { get; set; }
}
```

```
public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
```

В XAML просто сделайте DataTemplate.

XAML для WPF может выглядеть например так.

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextMessage}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                    <ItemsControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Images}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.Style>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            <StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AudioMessage}">
            <Grid>
                <MediaElement Source="{Binding Audio}"/>
            <Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

В зависимости от того, какой тип сообщения положите в коллекцию, тот шаблон для его отрисовки и выберет View.

Comment: Таким образом в коллекции могут находится объекты, которые были наследованы от класса Message, когда View начнет подхватывать Список Messages , она сама  будет отталкиваться от типа  Объекта внутри коллекции, и присваивать им нужный шаблон. Я все правильно понимаю ?

Comment: @КатяАппазова так точно. Так же я показал здесь, как использовать тригер на видимость контрола.

Comment: Спасибо большое